# Dependency Property stops updating after target property changes due to edit in UI

Tags: binding, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, dependency-properties

I have a custom dependency property on my control like so (boilerplate to implement the control left out):

```cs
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Value",
    typeof(String),
    typeof(BindingTestControl),
    new PropertyMetadata(null));

public static void SetValue(UIElement element, string value)
{
    element.SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
}
public static string GetValue(UIElement element)
{
    return (string)element.GetValue(ValueProperty);
}
```

I created a page with code-behind to bind to with relevant xaml like so (with `x:Name="root"` on the page):

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <local:BindingTestControl Value="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=StringItem}"/>
    <Button Width="200" Height="100" Tapped="Button_Tapped" FlowDirection="RightToLeft"/>
</Grid>
```

With code-behind like so (again, only relevant parts shown):

```cs
private string stringItem = "";
public string StringItem
{
    get
    {
        return stringItem;
    }
    set
    {
        this.stringItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("StringItem");
    }
}

int i = 0;
private void Button_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //i++;
    this.StringItem = "Test" + i;
}
```

This works fine the first time, but if I update the value in the Textbox, the binding won't overwrite the new value.  If I uncomment the `i++;` then the binding overwrites every time.  I'm assuming this happens this way because the value that is being sent with `INotifyPropertyChanged` is the same as the previous one despite the value in the `Textbox` no longer being the same.

Is there a way to force the value through the binding even if it hasn't changed?

Comment: Check the output window please. It should show you the any error happening while updating the biding source etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your setter to something like -

```
set
{
    this.stringItem = null;
    this.stringItem = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("StringItem");
}
```

Which should force the PropertyChanged event to fire as a change in value has occurred.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.